# Should I reply to an email saying that I requested online access to a website?

Tags: email, phishing, one-time-password, social-engineering

I received an email saying I requested access to a website. The email also includes a one-time passcode. I did not do anything that would require a one-time passcode. At the bottom of the email is a disclaimer saying something like "If you have received this message by mistake, please immediately notify us by replying to the message and delete the original message immediately thereafter."

I'm wondering if I should do this or not? It might be a good idea to reply to them in case someone is trying to hack into one of my accounts. Or someone tried to create an account with my email by mistake. Or it could be that they have a bug in their system so it would be a good idea to let them know. On the other hand, I'm worried that this could be a social engineering attack.

Comment: or someone used your email by mistake when they signed up for a service

Comment: @schroeder good point, I updated my question. In my case, the email was a little suspicious because it said something like "MODEL requested this" instead of someone's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely legitimate - there's little gain in getting you to reply to a spam email. All it reveals is that your email address is active, which isn't a particularly valuable piece of information.

To be safe, what you can do is instead of replying to the email, find the contact information for the alleged sender via a web search, then forward the email to that email address. This will ensure that the email goes to a legitimate party. If you want to hit the middle of the road, you can find out a legitimate email address for them, and check that the email that you received has the same domain - eg they will both end in @example.com. If they do, then replying to the original email will go to them. Be aware that unicode lookalike characters are a real risk with this approach.

Comment: I don't understand the point of forwarding the email to someone else. If it's someone who accidentally used my email address, then they might still go through with the authentication and create an account with my email, which is bad. But it could also be an attacker and they will have created an account with my email address, which is worse.

Comment: Per your post ""If you have received this message by mistake, please immediately notify us by replying to the message and delete the original message immediately thereafter." - If this is a legitimate email then the service provider wants to know. if this is an illegitimate email then forwarding it to the service provider is harmless. You are essentially figuring out what the contact information for the actual service provider is, then forwarding this email to that legitimate service provider.